# Nginx remove base url

Tags: nginx, django, rewrite, uwsgi

I'm trying to setup Django through UWSGI using Nginx.

I got the UWSGI pass to work using this function

```
                location / {
                        include        uwsgi_params;
                        uwsgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9001;
                }
```

Unfortunately when I visit /django/admin. I get an error

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://69.x.x.x/django/admin
Using the URLconf defined in Django.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/

How can I have nginx rewrite the url to not pass the /django part?

Answer (score 0):

There has to be something like the following in the `uwsgi_params` file:

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

These are the params passed to your application. I think you need to change the `request_uri` to $host in order to remove everything behind the hostname.

You can also set this variable inside the virtual server config as well, it should overwrite it locally. Do this before `uwsgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9001;`.

ALTERNATIVE METHOD
Also, you can create a rewrite rule as the following:

```
rewrite ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1 last;
```

and add it into the `location /` part, but I'm not sure this will work as expected.